# Scope storage video upload issue with retrofit 2 ( java.io.FileNotFoundException:open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

I Want to Upload the Video using Retrofit in API Level Q and Higher

1. I create a Media Helper which give me a list of Image and Video file

   ```
   return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
       val collectionWithPending = MediaStore.setIncludePending(collection)
       CursorLoader(context, collectionWithPending, projection, selection, null, sortOrder)
   } else {
       CursorLoader(context, collection, projection, selection, null, sortOrder)
   }
   ```
2. Media loading working fine with: **openFileDescriptor**

   ```
              image.context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(mData.contentUri!!, FILE_OPEN_READ_MODE).use {
               image.setPicture(mData.contentUri, RequestOptions().placeholder(R.color.white).error(R.color.white).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
           }
   ```
3. Two Different approach I have tried :

   1. With path : **/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1568101688613.jpg**. It's giving me error **open Access Denied**
   2. With content uri : **content://media/external/video/media/78**. It's giving me error **java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/media/external/video/media/78: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)**

I am using Retrofit for uploading the video

```
inline fun <reified T : Any>getRetrofit(): T {
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(getDefaultClient())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(getCustomConverterFactory())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build()

return retrofit.create(T::class.java)}
```

above is Retorfit Instance inline function

```
//Api call Interface
interface UploadImagesRetrofitService {
    @Multipart
    @POST(MEDIA)
    fun getUploadMedia(
        @Header(ID) xID: String? = null,
        @Header(MEDIA_TYPE) mediaType: String? = null,
        @Header(UPLOAD_TYPE) uploadType: String? = null,
        @Part files: MultipartBody.Part
    ): Observable<UploadMediaResponse>
}

//Access the Interface
fun getMediaUpload(xID: String, mediaType: String, uploadType: String, files: MultipartBody.Part): Observable<UploadMediaResponse> {
    return getRetrofitServiceTTU<UploadImagesRetrofitService>().getUploadMedia(xID, mediaType, uploadType, files)
}
```

Uploading Method

```
 fun getUpload(xID: String, mediaType: String, uploadType: String, files: MultipartBody.Part, height: Int = 0, width: Int = 0) {

    addDisposable(repo.getMediaUpload(xID, mediaType, uploadType, files).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe({
        if (it != null && it.reponseCode == 0) {
            it.height = height
            it.width = width
            it.mediaType = mMediaType
            mUploadingInterFace.getSuccessResponse(it)
        } else {
            mUploadingInterFace.getErrorResponse(it.responseError)
        }
    }, { thr ->
        thr.printStackTrace()
        if ((mContext?.isValid() == true) && mContext is BaseActivity) mContext.showError(mContext.getString(R.string.error_upload_media))
    }))
}
```

Comment: have you got any solution?